# Git - Re-attach to master and branch branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I created a branch `branch-1` from `master`, then made a bunch of commits on it, then faced two-options so branched from there and made a bunch of commit on the original branch `branch-1`, some on the new branch `branch-2`.

The commits on the original branch `branch-1` turned out to be a dead end (the ones after the second branching) but the one on the branch `branch-2` are meant to stay.

Is there a way to get rid of the first branch `branch-1` and keep only the second one with full history?

Comment: Why not just delete the first branch and keep working on the other?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to realize that in Git, *branches* are not the history.  *Commits* are the history.  (And there's no file history—there are just commits.)  Note that every commit has one "true name", which is its hash ID, the big ugly string of 40 hexadecimal characters like `f84b9b09d40408cf91bbc500d9f190a7866c3e0f`.

Each commit stores a full snapshot of your source tree, plus some metadata.  Here, the metadata is the more interesting part.  The metadata in a commit includes:

- your name and email address and a time-stamp;
- your log message; and
- the hash ID of its predecessor or *parent* commit.

This last item is the most important of all, in this particular context.  If we use one uppercase letter as a stand-in for the big ugly hash IDs, we can draw commits like this:

```
... <-F  <-G  <-H
```

where `H` is the *last* commit.  Commit `H` remembers the hash ID of `G`, so we say that `H` *points to* `G`.  Meanwhile `G` remembers its parent `F`, so `G` points to `F`, which points to `E`, and so on down the backwards chain.

This *is* the history in the repository.  Making a *new* commit consists of having Git freeze your source tree, add the log message and such, and come up with a new hash ID `I`.  The new commit `I` will store `H`'s hash ID:

```
... <-H  <-I
```

and now the history is one commit longer.

But: how do we know which commit is the *last* one in the chain?  In this simplified example, with uppercase letters, it's obvious, but with real hash IDs, which seem random, it's not.  In fact, there's nothing other than brute-force "list every commit, see which one is last" to find out.  So Git gives us *branch names*, which help puny humans (and Git itself since it's not that smart either) *find* the *last* commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

which becomes:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

after we make the new commit.

Put as simply as possible, a *branch name* just points to (contains the hash ID of) the *last* commit that we—and Git—should count as part of that branch.

This means that when you create a new branch, you pick some existing commit and tell Git to put another name on it:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, branch1
```

Now Git needs a way to know *which branch name to use*, so we have Git attach the special name `HEAD` to one of the two:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, branch1 (HEAD)
```

When we make our new commit, Git updates the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
```

Note that commit `H`, which is the tip of master, is *also* on branch `branch1`.

If you create another name, simply draw it in wherever it points.  If it points to `H`, draw it in pointing to `H`.  If it points to `I`, like `branch1`, draw it in pointing to `I`.  Then add some more commits, updating whichever name `HEAD` is attached-to:

```
             J--K   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- branch1
```

or:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- branch1
              \
               J--K   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

or whatever.

Let's say that at this point we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--L--M--N   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
              \
               J--K   <-- branch2
```

*Deleting* a branch (name) just means *erase the name*.  The *commits* remain undisturbed—one a commit is made, *nothing* can change it.  If you can no longer *find* the commit in the graph, the commit is now vulnerable to being removed.  But if you can start from some existing name, and work back to reach the commit, the commit itself is quote safe.  So if we `git checkout master` (so that we can delete `branch1`), we'll get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I--L--M--N   [abandoned]
              \
               J--K   <-- branch2
```

Commit `I` is still *reachable* by starting at `K`, from `branch2`, and working backwards: commit `I` was on both `branch1` *and* `branch2`.  Now that `branch1` is gone, `I` is only on `branch2`, but it's still reachable by Git's "walk backwards from all branch names" trick,

Commits `L-M-N`, however, have become unprotected.  After some time period—usually there's a grace period of at least 30 days, through a mechanism Git calls *reflogs*—Git's "garbage collector" will eventually run and clean up *unreachable* objects (commits and other objects).  Those commits will eventually go away entirely, leaving you with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I
              \
               J--K   <-- branch2
```

which makes it look like `branch1` never existed.